# How to convert image into google document to get the OCR text using App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, ocr, google-docs-api

Currently, I am uploading newspaper images (containing text) in my Google Drive which I want to convert into plain text using Google Docs OCR.

The primary reason to use this technique is that Google Docs supports multiple languages and is able to provide the OCR converted text with much higher accuracy compared to other OCR engines like Tesseract.

Comment: @NicEndo I have to run OCR on images containing native Indian languages which currently Google Vision OCR API doesn't support. But for some weird reason, it works by opening those images in Google Docs!